# Datatables init ajax request initial value

Tags: javascript, ajax, knockout.js, datatables

I have an app with datatables and knockout js.

KnockoutJS app is used to manage keywords (tags) for additional filtering table.

```
var table = $("#news").DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        url: "{{ base_url('news/load_news/full') }}",
        data: function (d) {
            d.keywords = ko.toJSON(keywords.keywords);
        }
    },
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "bFilter": false,
    "bLengthChange": false
});
```

The KnockoutJS model is populated when page loads, via an Ajax request.

The main issue I get is on the first Datatables Ajax request, I have empty keywords array. If I click update table button, `d.keywords` is not empty.

I think this issue because the Ajax request is async, so how do I force datatables wait until KnockoutJS app populated has populated?

==================

```
   function refresh_table() {
        table.ajax.reload(null, false); // reload DataTable
        fresh_news_alert.hide();
    }
```

Comment: if you share more code inc your update button it will be easy to track rather doing a rough guess .

Comment: This is almost all code. I just force datatables wait for some data at init Datatables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put your DataTable initialization in a custom binding. That will ensure it is not called before your Knockout viewmodel is initialized and bound.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses a custom binding that I created that depends on a knockout fork.  If you like this solution please leave a comment on the pull request to get it merged intp knockout 3.4, Thanks.

[example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zachpainter77/4tLabu56/)

[knockout pull request](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/pull/1856)

```
ko.bindingHandlers.DataTablesForEach = {

        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
             var nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(element.childNodes, 0);
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(nodes, function (node) {
                if (node && node.nodeType !== 1) {
                    node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
                }
            });
            return ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {

            var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()),
            key = "DataTablesForEach_Initialized";

            var newValue = function () {
                return {
                    data: value.data || value,
                    beforeRenderAll: function (el, index, data) {

                        if (ko.utils.domData.get(element, key)) {
                            $(element).closest('table').DataTable().clear();
                            $(element).closest('table').DataTable().destroy();
                        }
                    },
                    afterRenderAll: function (el, index, data) {
                        $(element).closest('table').DataTable(value.options);
                    }

                };
            };

            ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.update(element, newValue, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);

            //if we have not previously marked this as initialized and there is currently items in the array, then cache on the element that it has been initialized
            if (!ko.utils.domData.get(element, key) && (value.data || value.length)) {
                ko.utils.domData.set(element, key, true);
            }

            return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
        }
    };
```